# Shuffling blocks puzzle

Tags: mathematics, visual

We have 5 blocks denoted A, B, C, D, and E. Let's stack them in two layers such that block A and B are on the top and blocks C, D, and E are on the bottom. Call this arrangement **ABCDE**:

[image]

Let there be three groups consisting of blocks ACD, blocks ABD, and blocks BDE. Each move consists of choosing a group and shifting the blocks 1 position in the clockwise or counterclockwise direction.

For example, if we choose group ACD, we have to move block A into block D's place, block D into block C's place, and block C into block A's place. Similarly, we can move in the opposite direction, moving block A into block C's place, block C into block D's place, and block D into block A's place.

The same rule applies to group ABD and group BDE.

Can you get **EDCBA** and **BACDE** from **ABCDE**? Why or why not?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: Yes! It's an extension of something I read in a book and was wondering if it's solvable.

Comment: Mind citing the book you got inspiration from? That way people might be able to look at the other puzzle and gain some insight.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the problem "is this reachable from ABCDE" is equivalent to "is the number of swaps you'd take to get there by just swapping pairs even?" though I don't have the brainpower at this hour to give a rigorous proof.

Comment: The reference you'll really want is the alternating group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's put this into mathematical language:

> We're looking at the action of the group $S_5$ on a set $X$ of 5 elements $A,B,C,D,E$. Specifically, we're interested in the subgroup $H\leq S_5$ generated by three 3-cycles $(A,B,D)$, $(A,C,D)$, $(B,D,E)$. I will prove exactly what subgroup $H$ is, and thereby answer the two questions you gave.

1. Can you get **BACDE** from ABCDE?

   > **NO**, because BACDE is just a transposition away from ABCDE, and every 3-cycle is a product of two transpositions so we can never get an odd product of transpositions by combining them. In group theory language, we know that $H\leq A_5$.
2. Can you get **EDCBA** from ABCDE?

   > **YES**, because EDCBA is an even product of transpositions away from ABCDE, and I will now show that $H=A_5$.
   >
   >  Clearly, $H$ is transitive on the whole set $(A,B,C,D,E)$.
   >  Also, the subgroup of $H$ generated by the $(A,B,D)$ and $(A,C,D)$ cycles is transitive on the set $(A,B,C,D)$ but stabilises the element $E$.
   >  Finally, the subgroup of $H$ generated by just $(A,B,D)$ is transitive on the set $(A,B,D)$ but stabilises the elements $D$ and $E$.
   >  By the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem, the order of $H$ must be a multiple of $3$ and $4$ and $5$, therefore a multiple of $60$. But $H\leq A_5$ and the order of $A_5$ is $60$, so $H$ must be the whole of $A_5$.
   >
   >  Since $H$ is the whole of $A_5$, that means every element of $A_5$ can be reached by combining the allowed operations, and in particular **EDCBA** can be reached from ABCDE.

Hat-tip to [Derek Holt at Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837104) for inspiration. The above link is about a different problem, but Derek's argument used there also works here.

Comment: Actually the result is the same without ABD.